# preg_match is working on one server but not other

Tags: php, regex, ftp

I have the same php preg_match script, checking the same file, on two linux servers they are not resulting  the same way (same php version). Trying to check if there are any horses today at my local track. I tried preg_last_error shows no error.

```
$pattern='/<p class=\"clear\" style=\"margin-top:-17px;\">&nbsp;<\/p> -->

    <h4 class=\"lightgreenbg padding\">/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $HTMLcontent)) { echo ("Found races today. <br>"); } else { echo ("No races found."); }
```

The $HTMLcontent can be found one [server1](http://luckytime7.com/logs/horsetemp.html) and [server2](http://century-media.com/logs/horsetemp.html). Not sure if this is encoding, php, or ftp problem. When I FTP the data from server 1 to server 2 it also stops working on server 2. But when I download it to my PC and then FTP server 2 works fine. Very strange.

Comment: I guess it's due to the version of `php`. I had a similar problem some time ago.

Comment: Probably not related to your actual problem, but consider using a parser instead of trying to fiddle with regular expressions on the DOM.

Comment: [Same file but not same content.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9Z67.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be due to a difference in line endings if your server and workstation use different operating systems. Windows/Dos uses `\r\n` whereas linux uses just `\n`.

You can solve this by matching any whitespace rather than the exact whitespace - you do this using `\s`:

```
$pattern='/<p class=\"clear\" style=\"margin-top:-17px;\">&nbsp;<\/p> -->\s+<h4 class=\"lightgreenbg padding\">/';
```

If it wasn't for the line endings, then you are not actually searching for a regular expression, just a string. so I would say definitely don't use preg_match as strpos is much more efficient:

```
<?php
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
?>
```

From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Yes that worked. I forgot about \s. It is definitely a difference between linux and windows. When saved it on my windows PC, it used a different newline than the linux machine. Thought I losing my mind. Thank you!